# Unable to pin FloatingActionButton when Toolbar collapse

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

I have fragment inside a viewpager, so the fragment consist of a Recyclerview and FloatingActionButton. So when i scroll the recyclerview the toolbar collapse and tablayout pins, but floating action button also scrolls up. I want to pin the FlaotingActionButton to its position.

Please check the image -
[image: Initial position of FloatingActionButton]

Now when i scroll the toolbar collpase and floatingactionbutton also moves up. -
[image: FloatingActionButton moves up.]

Please let me know how to pin the FloatingActionButton in bottom-right.

Thi is the XML file -

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_grey_200" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_icon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/recycler_view"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="right|bottom|top|left"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try change fab anchor to this: @+id/coordinatorLayout

Comment: @BrunoFerreira this did not work. Says view cannot be anchor to parent layout.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_icon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="right|bottom|top|left"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
```

Comment: still not working. Still the FAB scrolls up and down